# How to return the number of Posts Tagged with "example" using acts_as_taggable under ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable

How to return the number of Posts Tagged with "example" using acts_as_taggable under ROR

currently I am implementing this by declare

```
<%=Questions.find_tagged_with("example", :match_all => true).size%>
```

I wonder if there is any other better solutions out there, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a named scope in the model, then calling count on it, e.g.

```
named_scope :tagged_with, lambda {|tag| find_options_for_find_tagged_with(tag)}
```

then:

```
Questions.tagged_with("example").count
```

Or something to that effect. `find_options_for_find_tagged_with` is defined in `acts_as_taggable`.